# SH CLI sed remove all characters besides path from listing

Tags: regex, linux, sed, sh

There is a file that has results of `rsync` files listing:

```
drwxrwxrwx          4,096 2018/12/10 15:27:39 test/dir/one
drwxrwxrwx          4,096 2018/12/10 15:27:39 best/folder/two
```

how to use `sed` to get rid of everything besides paths?

wanted result:

```
test/dir/one
best/folder/two
```

I tried this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Lxqfys/1): that works as it should for finding preceding of paths as base for `sed` but it did not have any effect when used:

```
cat listing.txt | sed 's/.*[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ //' | less
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Add option `-E` or `-r` to sed.

Comment: @Cyrus I edited question, actually information comes form rsync, but in general I'm looking for a way to use sed to change the listing from whatever tool it was coming from.

Comment: @Cyrus `-E` or `-r` worked well.

Comment: or escape every + with a \.

Comment: @Cyrus post it as answer and i'll accept it

Comment: ` awk -F' ' '{print $5}' file.txt `

Comment: @KavyeshShah: Unfortunately, this does not work if path and/or filename contains spaces.

Comment: `-F`  in command stands for field separator and i used field separator as space.

Comment: [Get basename of filename or directory name](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-basename-of-filename-or-directory-name/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` probably doesn't support the `+` repetition operator in this form. Try

```
sed 's/.*[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+ //' listing.txt
```

(which also does away with that pesky [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)).

Recall that `sed` predates many of the frills of modern regex. Your `sed` might support an `-r` or `-E` flag to enable extended regex support (whioh is still far from the modern regex dialect many newcomers are most familiar with) but this is not portable.

Of course, if the listing uses a fixed field width, maybe simply try

```
cut -c47- listing.txt
```

(Not in a place where I can verify the precise number - play around with different values.)

Comment: `cut -c47-` there you go

Comment: Assuming that the block size date and  time doesn't change, I guess the number `47`  depends on the permissions which should be of fixed width.

Comment: @tripleee Both of examples worked well. Not escaping `+` was the issue for `sed`. Now I recall I had the same issue when used regex into `VIM`. Don't know why I missed `cut`. It is so obvious now :). On 1000k lines `cut` had 2sec execution time vs `sed`'s 11sec.

Comment: The sed command assumes no file names contain spaces preceded by N:N:N where N is 1 or more digits. Since `\+` is a GNU extension and GNU sed also supports `-E` you could just use that.

Comment: Personally, my first suggestion would be [col](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html).  Followed by [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).  Then [sed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk).

Comment: @EdMorton `\+` is a POSIX extension I believe.

Comment: @triplee no, it's a GNU extension. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html: `\+
    As *, but matches one or more. It is a GNU extension.`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks! I had imagined this extension was defined by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) just like `\{m,n\}` etc but ... TIL.

Comment: Yeah looks like POSIX just defined `\{m,n\}` so then they didn't need to define `\+` and `\?` (as GNU has) since you can do them both with `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}` respectively.

Comment: @paulsm4 can you please post a `col` answer? I just read the man page and can't imagine how it'd apply to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work using any POSIX sed even if your file names contain blanks:

```
$ sed 's/\([^ ]* *\)\{4\}//' file
test/dir/one
best/folder/two
```

or any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/([^ ]* *){4}/,"")}1' file
test/dir/one
best/folder/two
```

If your file names can contain newlines then we should talk....